# Unable to make button show or hide depending on whether another element has content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So this is probably a simple question. But I have to ask because it's not doing what I want.

Here is the button JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($(".saved-items").html().length > 0) {
     $('.btn-01').show();
   }                                           
 });
```

The button is shown if there is content in the div. But I would like it to hide again if the div has no content.

I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       if ($(".saved-items").html().length > 0) {
         $('.btn-01').show();
       }
       if ($(".saved-items").html().length < 0) {
         $('.btn-01').hide();
       }
 });
```

Here is the HTML when an item is added:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="saved-items"><h4>Items:</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><i class="fa fa-anchor" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#f60;margin-right:10px;"></i>RAW</li>
        </ul>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.btn-01').toggle($(".saved-items").html().trim().length > 0);               
         });
        </script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">                  
        <a class="fancybox my-subject" href="#contact-formulier" value="Item X"><div style="display: block;" class="btn-01">Check Out</div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the HTML without any items saved:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="saved-items">
    <h4>Items:</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
 <a class="fancybox my-subject" href="#contact-formulier" value="Item X"><div class="btn-01">Check Out</div></a>
</div>
```

But no go. Here is the CSS of btn-01:

```
.btn-01 {
    background: #f60;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
    width: 90%;
    display: none;
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: How can the length of a string be less than zero? It should be `== 0`, or rather just use `else` instead of trying to make a new condition for the only logical alternative.

Comment: So the script isn't present if there are no items? How's it going to run then? Either way, you obviously have HTML still in there, so clearly it'll never be `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

length of string is zero or greater than zero..can't be less than zero.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($(".saved-items").html().length > 0) {
     $('.btn-01').show();
   }else{
       $('.btn-01').hide();
   }
});
```

please check https://jsfiddle.net/Shilpi/uhfruo1a/2/

Comment: Your answer is correct but it doesn't make sense to write it this way. Also "use the code" is a poor explanation of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toggle()` to achieve this:

```
$('.btn-01').toggle($(".saved-items").html().trim().length > 0);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/qnqe0qfk/)

Comment: Toggle doesn't work. It just display's the button, when it's == 0 the button is still there.

Comment: That's not possible, however the issue may be caused by whitespace in the `html()` value causing the length to be `> 0` even when there is no perceived value. I updated the answer to include `trim()`

Comment: Can it check for elements? Because when I remove an item from my cart it still has a little html in it. Is it possible to have it react to an <i> element?

Comment: At this point it would be more helpful if you updated the question with the details of your HTML (or started a new one with all information included), otherwise any answer I give would be pure guesswork.